# Dual Axis Hinge

Tags: hinges

I'm not sure if there is a better community for this question, if so please let me know!

I'm trying to figure out what type of "hinge" has 2 pivots perpendicular to each other.

The idea being: a flat item, such as a desk top, is in the x-y plane with an attachment point for something like a curved leg which was in the x-z plane.
With the "hinge" the leg could pivot to move into the y-z plane and then "fold" down to be in the x-y plane, like the desk top.

An example would be like those one arm desk tops in colleges or lecture halls that you lift the desk up and then rotate it around.

I've looked around and found some things that match, but I'm not sure if there is a name for this type of thing. What seems like it is a "dual-axis" hinge, or a "perpendicular hinge". But these terms still seem to pull in random unrelated things that don't match.

Is there a name for this type of attachment pivot connector? What would that be called?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is called an "articulating hinge". If you web image search that term, you will see many examples in different form factors.